# Prevent a predicate expression tree from compilation

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

I have a code as below

```
 Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> criteria = null;
 string name = rawCriterion.Substring(0, rawCriterion.IndexOf("_"));
 criteria = (x => x.Name == name);
 return criteria;
```

I am expecting this code it runs, the output in the criteria variable would be `x => x.Name == "WhatEverValueInVariable"` but what I get is `x => x.Name ==(MyProject.Models+MyClass+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).name)`

Any idea what is the problem? and how to keep my predicate as a tree?

Comment: Are you just talking about that the debugger shows you?

Comment: Yes, isn't that the same value will be sent to any linq provider (linq to entities)? will this predicate run successfully in EF?

Comment: No, that's just the debugger view, Linq2Entities will deconstruct the expression properly.

Comment: Your code sets `criteria` to `x-> x.Name == name` - why would you think the variable `name` would be expanded into its value? The variable is captured (using a hidden class) and the lambda expression references the captured variable, in case `name` is changed before the lambda is executed.

Comment: Your predicate **is** a tree. Just the tree contains  captured **variable** rather than constant value (`Expression.Constant`). There is way to embed constant expression at compile time except if `name` is actually `const string`. From the other side, this allows translators like EF to bind parameter instead of value.

Comment: @NetMage You are right, but it would have been nice if C# provided a way to bind a value instead of a variable. Close Over Value vs Close Over Variable :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Working on it ;)

Comment: @IvanStoev Of course, it is already written: [Building an IQueryable Provider - Part III](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii/)

Comment: BTW, @IvanStoev in your comment, did you mean There is _no_ way?

Comment: @NetMage There is **no** way at **compile** time. It can easily be done with `Expression` methods.

Comment: @IvanStoev Just trying to point out your comment says the opposite, but it is too late now.

Comment: @NetMage Got ya - I have eaten the word **no** :) You are right, that's exactly what I meant.